# Driving a solenoid via a digital output

Tags: microcontroller, driver, inductive, solenoid-valve, diode-clamp

What are the effects of the pull-down resistor (33K) when the solenoid-valve enters its turn-off phase? Will it prevent the solenoid-valve from ever discharging because current would flow from ground through the pull-down resistor to the solenoid-valve? How do we protect the mosfet (e.g. clamping) when the solenoid is in the turn-off phase? If Ids Max is 2A and the solenoid IPeak was 25mA (derived from 0.35W solenoid spec), should I even be concerned about protecting the mosfet during the turn-off phase? The solenoid-valve RL circuit is modeled after a turn-on time of 20msec and it being powered at 0.35W.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you using a source follower NFET here? Do you have a datasheet for the relay? (Just curious about it.)

Comment: Agree with previous comment.  Do you have a datasheet for the solenoid?  
The problem with this arrangement is that the FET may not stay ON as the voltage across the load increases.

Comment: @Troutdog see above edits. I've attached the MCU diagram. There's really no electrical datasheet for the solenoid. I've just modeled it after the fact that it has a 20ms response time and requires 0.35W to operate.

Comment: I suppose the 20ms includes the reaction time of the mechanical parts of the solenoid, not just the electrical inductance, so it's probably lower than your estimate. (No problem, though)

Comment: Your driver circuit is fundamentally wrong in the way you have used your MOSFET. It's a source follower and you'll be lucky to get 2 volts out of the source when the MCU drives 3.3 volts. You might get 3.5 volts out if the MCU drive level is 5 volts so, there's no need for a 12 volt supply because, and trust me on this, you'll get nowhere near 12 volts at the source, not in a hundred years. There is absolutely no-chance that you can drive 25 mA into your solenoid with that circuit.

Comment: @Andy aka I have no idea what the actual MOSFET configuration is -- that drawing is referencing a figure from the manual for the digital output, which I've attached in the second figure. The actual circuit does indeed supply 12V at above 25 mA, it just might be drawn wrong here and I have no way of knowing what the actual implementation is because I didn't design the digital output device. I'm just trying to demonstrate a switching MOSFET.

Comment: @user2063586 What do the dotted lines signify in your drawing?

Comment: @Troutdog Two separate pieces of hardware.

Comment: OK.  I think I understand.  The usual method to protect the FET is to place a flyback or catch diode across the inductive load (cathode towards the positive side).  The diode will clamp the negative spike to one diode drop below ground in this case.   It may be the case that there is protection inherent in the circuit already.  A 33K resistor is too large to act as protection here.  It may be there simply to drain all charge out of the circuit when off.

Comment: @Troutdog I have never done high-side switching on an inductive load, I'm use to low-side switching. I just realized that the flyback diode is the same thing as the clamping diode. I had though you would want different protections if you switch high-side vs low-side, but it looks like the flyback diode would have the same impact (e.g. clamping the output to GND). Is there any performance draw backs for switching between high-side and low-side?

Comment: The first diagram is hand-drawn and unlikely to be from a manual for something. So, if you "have no idea what the actual MOSFET configuration is" then who made that drawing? So, given it can't work being driven from an MCU, the rest of your question about MOSFET protection is null and void.

Comment: It's hand drawn because I just combined the drawings from two different manuals and I figured it'd be easier to hand draw it, that's why there's dotted lines in the drawing.

Comment: Any high side circuit has a low-side equivalent.  Low side is often preferred due to the wide range of N-channel devices available.  High side requires the use of a P-channel device or a charge pump for the gate driver.  The flyback diode does the same thing in either case by dissipating the energy stored in the inductor when the switch (FET) is turned off (this also limits the voltage spike).

Comment: @Troutdog So I should expect no noticeable difference between a high-side driven solenoid-valve and a low-side driven solenoid-valve? The differences seem to be more in the implementation of the digital output MCU (sinking vs sourcing implementations).

Comment: For a low-power circuit like this, there would be no difference, assuming the appropriate engineering was done in both solutions.  High side and low side are both valid approaches.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the effects of the pull-down resistor (33K) when the solenoid-valve enters its turn-off phase?

It is in parallel with the coil, so will serve to discharge the current in the coil.

> Will it prevent the solenoid-valve from ever discharging because current would flow from ground through the pull-down resistor to the solenoid-valve?

No, it will help discharge the solenoid in a more controlled manner.

Without it, the solenoid will discharge even faster, but produce a much higher reverse peak voltage when shut off.

With a lower value such as 1k, the solenoid will discharge slower, but produce a much smaller reverse peak voltage when shut off.

> How do we protect the MOSFET (e.g. clamping) when the solenoid is in the turn-off phase?

If speed is not an issue, then a garden-variety 1N400x diode is used instead of a resistor.  This makes the coil open very slowly, but blocks the peak reverse spike to -0.7V or so.

> If Ids Max is 2A and the solenoid IPeak was 25mA (derived from 0.35W solenoid spec), should I even be concerned about protecting the MOSFET during the turn-off phase?

Absolutely.  The inductance is stated as 3.2 Henries, which is a fair amount of inductance.  Such an inductor could make spikes in the kilovolts range.  Without some means to clamp that spike, it will destroy the MOSFET.

Comment: I see 3 point 2 henries

Comment: It's 3.2H. It's derived the following way: 3tau = 20ms -> 3L/R = 0.02. R is assumed to be 480 from the fact that the solenoid is 0.35W, so steady state current draw will be at 25mA

Comment: Thanks, been squinting at tiny parts all day and eyesight is not what it used to be.  Neither is brainpower either, apparently. :)

Answer (score 1):

When the MOSFET is turned off (gate voltage presumably goes to 0V) the solenoid will continue to draw 25mA at whatever voltage that ends up being.

I calculate that the 33K resistor could develop up to 825 volts across it (that is 25mA times 33000 ohms). If the resistor were the only current path this voltage would surely destroy the MOSFET. You might even get a small arc somewhere.

However, the other path is through the MOSFET. If the gate is at 0 volts and the threshold voltage is - let's say - 3 volts, the source can go down to -3 volts and then the MOSFET turns partially on. This won't destroy the MOSFET, however it will dissipate the turnoff current. Again using the 3 volt threshold example, it would have to be able to dissipate up to 15 volts (12 **+** 3) times 25mA which is 0.375 watts.

Not a huge amount, so no additional protection is needed.

If the MOSFET is inside the microcontroller I would not rely on it to work this way as you don't know the exact circuitry inside the microcontroller, but you indicated that it's a separate MOSFET so it should be okay.

However, dissipating the 12 volts is an unnecessary waste of power. It's probably acceptable, being a small fraction of a joule of extra waste each time the solenoid turns off, but it can be avoided if the output's voltage is clamped to above the negative threshold voltage (e.g. by the usual clamping diode).

[A quick Falstad simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEA2AzNA7ATi8gHACxhaKTJYgKSUgGqUCmAtGGAFAA2Iqh4BB3XgCZIeKN2hCQQ6HgxCECNFgXzsYDMwxQ2AJ0ECRYnobxjqBPJD3gV4DMltSh88alTw2Adyf3HxKTB+HR8AvgETcOlvXxdAuyEzENikyMTzNgBzFLEw1BFxawAzcESQXF8K-PBoJBhIIRiw1njA4OtQuytfSx0AJR7cuzBHagtqMCkxqFq2AcmxCu6KgSQwNanC2YB7cWQBcZxpMdgFcU3UNl2BffECSCOC+rOIKQi2IA) agrees with me.

Comment: Can the clamping diode be implemented on the MOSFET? I'm planning on reaching out to the manufacturer to ask about the MOSFET. I'm just not sure if I should expect a clamping diode to be present in this device as it's not demonstrated in their simple schematic.

Comment: @user2063586 it would be connected between ground and the output, therefore it cannot be part of the mosfet.

Comment: If they had an internal diode connected in this fashion, would that be sufficient?

Comment: Is the clamping diode the same as the flyback diode? E.g. if I have a diode in parallel with the solenoid, will this clamp the output voltage? I'm use to low-side switching, so I wasn't really sure what the considerations are for high-side switching.

Comment: @user2063586 It's the same thing as the flyback diode (different word, same thing), and your circuit doesn't have one